# How to access dictionary key having colon

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am having dictionary(JSON i think),
As a response I am getting below value...

```
{
    "servers": [
        {
            "status": "ACTIVE",
            "updated": "2014-06-12T01:13:47Z",
            "hostId": "e60cf1024aecbddd13805ea01d4702ccfcf2c2de0f67a205b143ca07",
            "OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:host": "ubi1",


        }
    ]
}
```

in this how do i access

```
OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:host
```

value but I am getting `status` and `updated` keys.

How do i do that?

Thanks.

Comment: _"in this how do i access `OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:host`?"_ That data doesn't appear anywhere in that dictionary, so I guess you can't.

Comment: Show us the Python code you're using.

Comment: before posting site validated object, so i removed most of the content .

Answer (score 1):

Your dictionary has one key "servers" who's value is a list of dictionaries.  Those internal dictionaries have to be accessed either in a loop or by index.

```
data =  {
"servers":
 [
    {
        "status": "ACTIVE",
        "updated": "2014-06-12T01:13:47Z",
        "hostId": "e60cf1024aecbddd13805ea01d4702ccfcf2c2de0f67a205b143ca07",
        "OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:host": "ubi1",
    },
 ],
 }
```

Example of in a loop

```
 for server in data['servers']:
     print(server['OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:host'])

 >>>> ubi1
```

or direct index

```
 print(data['servers'][0]['OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:host'])
 >>>> ubi1
```

Comment: The first part of your answer seems incorrect now :P

Comment: How does it seem incorrect, the servers data is iterated through in a loop, so "server" is a dict element of the "servers" list and then you access the key (as a string) to return the value.  Works for me on python2.7

Comment: I was just talking about the very first line of your answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

`variable_that_holds_dictionary['servers'][0]['OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:host']`

Answer (score 0):

This will print the value

```
data = {
    "servers": [
        {
            "status": "ACTIVE",
            "updated": "2014-06-12T01:13:47Z",
            "hostId": "e60cf1024aecbddd13805ea01d4702ccfcf2c2de0f67a205b143ca07",
            "OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:host": "ubi1",
        }
    ]
}

host = data["servers"][0]["OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:host"]
print host # for python 3, you use print(host) instead

>>> ubi1
```

To get the value, first you need to access the "servers" in the data with `data["servers"]` then to get the dictionary in that list you use `[0]` because its the first and only element and after that you get the value of "OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:host" with `["OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:host"]`

Answer (score 0):

there Few steps :

1. first thing is your saying *JSON i think*  so first clearify what it is
2. if it is json  then using `json.loads(<ur json string>)` this converts in to python object(i.e, dictionary)
3. then call directly `data["servers"][0]["OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:host"]` to get value

or if it Dictionary then directly u can call `data["servers"][0]["OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:host"]`

Comment: No need for the json stuff, the data is already in a dict :-)

Comment: @TimCastelijns OP is saying he thinks JSON. so a precautionary step i took :)